# Copied file names becomes garbled

Tags: php

I have PHP installed on a CentOS server, and I wanna transfer files from this (with PHP FTP) to a Windows FTP server that is running IIS. Now my problem, when the file name have non-latin characters it changes file names to something like 'ØªØ³Øª.3gp' (its name in CentOS is تست.3gp) I 've searched many times but no solutions. How can I fix this?

I think Windows use CP-1252 (Windows-1252) as charset and CentOS use UTF-8 as charset. But converting this with `iconv()` and `mb_convert_encoding()` didn't work.

Comment: see this page i answered this question there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055192/why-does-windows-need-to-utf8-decode-filenames-for-file-get-contents-to-work/15055869#15055869

Comment: it work correctly for me what is the problem?

Comment: Is there a need to retain the original file name?

Comment: I try to user urlencode() but not working then try to convert file name too utf-16 but not working. in urlencode it is the same to do noting to file name, for utf-16 it says access denied for ftp_put() function

Comment: try  first rename files inside of CentOS by Unicode utf-16 or Windows-1252 then send it to window server.

Comment: maybe you dont have that language installed n winshit or there is someting wrong with ftp ....

Comment: I have installed all Asian languages and can make this file by remote desktop

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer after many researches. windows use different charset for different languages. and for coding to these charset we can use this class: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1360-PHP-Conversion-between-many-character-set-encodings.html

Answer (score 0):

also we can use these codings in `mb_convert_encoding()`:

```
// Cyrillic script such as Russian, Bulgarian, Serbian Cyrillic and other languages Windows-1251 ~= ISO-8859-5 

// Latin alphabet Windows-1252 ~= ISO-8859-1 // sometimes called incorrectly "ANSI"

//modern Greek. It is not capable of supporting the older polytonic Greek. It is not fully compatible with ISO 8859-7 because the letters like Ά are located at different byte values Windows-1253 ~= ISO-8859-7

// Turkish Windows-1254 = ISO-8859-9

// Hebrew Windows-1255 = ISO-8859-8

// Arabic script like Persian and Urdu Windows-1256 ~= ISO-8859-6

// Estonian, Latvian and Lithuanian languages Windows-1257 != ISO-8859-4

// Vietnamese texts. It is very similar to Windows-1252 with the differences being that s-caron and z-caron Windows-1258 ~= Windows-1252
```

I use these codes for persian file names:

```
$filename=iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1256//IGNORE',$filename);
```