# PHP - Mixed charset filenames (Latin, Japanese, Korean) error with RecursiveDirectoryIterator + RecursiveIteratorIterator + RegexIterator

Tags: php, json, character-encoding, multilingual, jplayer

I'm reading my music directory to populate a JSON for jPlayer, as follow:

```
<?php
//tried utf-8, shift_jis, etc. No difference
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=SHIFT_JIS');

//cant be blank so i put . to make current file dir as base
$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.');
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+\.mp3$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
//instead of glob(*/*.mp3) because isnt recursive

$filesJson = [];

foreach ($Regex as $key => $value) {
    $whatever = str_ireplace(['.mp3','.\\'], '', $key);
    $filesJson['mp3'][] = [
        'title' => htmlspecialchars($whatever),
        'mp3' => $key
    ];

}
echo json_encode($filesJson);
exit();
?>
```

The problem lies in files which filename isn't standard UTF-8 - as Latin, Japanese and Korean  ones. Examples:

**Japanese**

[image]

**Korean**

[image]

**Latin (pt-br)**

[image]

Which converts into `?`, or simply becomes `null` when parsing latin names ( `Geração` or `4º` for e.g.)

[image]

---

So, how make the filenames/paths be parsed correctly with different kinds of languages?
The header charset isn't helping.

#### Info:

XAMPP with Apache2 + PHP 5.4.2 at Win7 x86

---

#### Update #1:

Tried @infinity's answer but no changes. Still `?` on JP, `null` on Latin.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.');
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+\.mp3$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

$filesJson = [];

foreach ($Regex as $key => $value) {
    $whatever = mb_substr($key, 2, mb_strlen($key)-6, "utf-8"); // 2 to remove .\ and -6 to remove .mp3 (-4 + -2)
    $filesJson['mp3'][] = [
        'title' => $whatever, //tried with and without htmlspecialchars
        'mp3' => $key
    ];

}
echo json_encode($filesJson);
exit();
?>
```

If I use `HTML-ENTITIES` instead of `utf-8` on `mb_substr()`, latin characters works but asian still `?`.

Comment: Do you have control over how the file names are written in the system?

Comment: @MikeBrant I do but having to rename all filenames of like.... 60GB+ of soundtrack isn't something 'fun'.

Comment: Try adding /u modifier to regex, i.e. '/^.+\.mp3$/ui'

Comment: tbh, problems with mixed charsets will drive you crazy and kill your code sooner or later. Better try to fix your input (in thi case your filenames) and go from there with a clean utf-8 (which supports ALL languages). Having to constantly switch and convert in your code WILL break your code and yourself.

Comment: @maxivanov with `u`, the latin ones disappear from the listing (not even as `null`) while japanese stays `?`.

Comment: @ToBe Currently I will only use for my self entertainment but I was expecting to fix it so I could use on a project I'm working to manage the current soundtracks available for the autoDJ function on centova,shoutcast,etc(which in my case,it's a asian music webradio).Therefore most annoying having to fix each file's name since I won't be the one uploading the content most of time.But yeah,I've worked with mixed charsets on HTML and was a chaos already.The point is that I feel the problem lies more on how RecursiveIterator and the Regexp return than the other parts of the code.

Comment: Did you try using the old style directory iteration via dir() and/or did you try filtering your files not via Regex but via plain old if and a non-complex "compare last 4 letters to '.mp3' method? Might be best to check on those suspected parts with regexp and RecursiveIterator first.

Comment: @ToBe Could you post an example as answer? I tried with `dir` but I failed in making it recursive. Because sometimes is `musicfolder\the_album\songfile.ext` but sometimes is `musicfolder\the_band\the_album\songfile.ext` for example.

Comment: You would have to write your own recursive function, I'll check if I got something in a drawer somewhere...

Comment: did you find solution to the problem?

Comment: @infinity Nope. I kinda gave up trying after the answers didn't helped much solving and since I was making at first as own entertainment (even if I could use it later for a better autoDJ script), I stopped giving so much time to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');

foreach ($Regex as $key => $value) {
    $whatever = mb_substr($key, 0, mb_strlen($str)-4, "utf-8");
    // ... rest of code
}
```

Comment: `Call to undefined function mb_substring()` but I just checked xampp's `php.ini`, the line `extension=php_mbstring.dll` is uncommented and the dll exists on `php\ext` folder. Using PHP 5.4.16. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry my bad, the function is `mb_substr` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Comment: No worries, thanks for correcting. Well, I changed to the correct function and changed that `$str` for `$key` but yet the same thing: Japanese is ?, latin becomes null. I've updated question with your code.

Answer (score 1):

A short try on a recursive approach using dir():

```
myRecursiveScanDir($mypath);

function myRecursiveScanDir($path)
    $d = dir($path);
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {

       // Do something, ie just echo it
       echo $path."/".entry."<br/>";

       if(is_dir($path."/".entry))
           myRecursiveScanDir($path."/".entry);
    }
    $d->close();
)
```

getting file extension and/or basename could be a bit problematic too. You might have to debug and test how mb_substr,pathinfo and basename react to such filenames.

Comment: `Cannot redeclare scanDir()` :( Seems already [exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: Changed tha function name. You should allways understand what you copy. Code is untested to show how you could do it. It's hardly a perfect working and fireproofed setup. ;)

Comment: I did changed the name, as I would in javascript and etcetera. But started getting warns about a third parameter which I had no idea of where it was getting called. Will test again. Normally when I don't know enough to actually fix, I don't try to mess much with it.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system you're using may be important in this case:

Please reffer to this question: [Why does Windows need to `utf8_decode` filenames for `file_get_contents` to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055192/why-does-windows-need-to-utf8-decode-filenames-for-file-get-contents-to-work)

I think it may be relevant since the screenshots look very *Microsoftish*.

Answer (score 0):

to match any letter/digits

> **`\p{L}\p{N}`**