# php file_get_contents Arabic Characters

Tags: php, file, arabic

Hello I have a problem in my PHP code :
I need to open a txt file using file_get_contents, the directory to the txt file contains arabic Characters 
my code:

```
$URLX = "C:/server files/BN/public_html" ; 
$BookName = "الإضافةإلىمفاوضةمالكحسون" ; 
$eachChapiter[$x] = "مالكمالكحسون" ; 

$content = file_get_contents($URLX."/".$BookName."/".str_replace(' ', '', $eachChapiter[$x]).".txt");
```

the error output :

```
WARNING: FILE_GET_CONTENTS(C:/SERVER FILES/BN/PUBLIC_HTML/الإضافةإلىمفاوضةمالكحسون/مالكمالكحسون.TXT): FAILED TO OPEN STREAM: NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\LIBRARY\SEARCH\SEARCH.PHP ON LINE 30

NOTICE: UNDEFINED OFFSET: 1 IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\LIBRARY\SEARCH\SEARCH.PHP ON LINE 38
```

Comment: php isn't unicode aware. you can't use php's standard string functions on unicode text without destroying the text. use the `mb_*()` functions instead, which ARE unicode-aware

Comment: According to [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708017/can-a-php-file-name-or-a-dir-in-its-full-path-have-utf-8-characters), PHP's file functions can't open any files that have paths with characters outside ISO-8859-1. Arabic is not part of that encoding, so it's not possible. The `mb_*()` family of functions will not help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Mike for helping me correct the answer. So As per the question and OP's OS it seems that you(OP) are encountering a variant of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055192/why-does-windows-need-to-utf8-decode-filenames-for-file-get-contents-to-work) error.

And as discussed on that link, you can use the following code to detect the file name encoding

```
...    

$final_url = $URLX."/".$BookName."/".str_replace(' ', '', $eachChapiter[$x]);

mb_detect_encoding($final_url, 'UTF-8', true)) ? utf8_decode($final_url) : $final_url;
$content = file_get_contents($final_url).".txt");
```

Remember that this code will create problems(again discussed on that link) on a linux server. So if you are using Linux production environment then you can apply the solution suggested there.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure if this applies in *this* case, where the problem appears to have to do with an Arabic *file name.* It sounds to me like the other answer might be closer to the mark in *this* case, although I agree that your answer might be proper in *other* cases where multinational-encoded strings are being used.

Comment: Are you using windows OS?

Comment: Suggest that you edit your answer one more time:  "Are you using Windows OS?" It sure does appear to me that he *is.*  So, edit your answer to tell us just *what* you're thinking might be relevant, "assuming" that it is, indeed, Windows.  **:-)**  *"Are you using Windows OS?  Because, if so ..."* (etc.)

Comment: @MikeRobinson yup :D I missed the file directory location :)

Comment: I have always resolved that I wont provide answers when high on ****, but I always break that. #addicted_to_so :D

Comment: Hey, I didn't downvote you!  Quite the opposite.  **:-)**

Comment: thanks guys for your reply , I'm using Windows Server 2012.